# Return clickable URL from text URL in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm working on a cascading dropdown list. When the last item is selected, it pulls up info from a .cs list based on all of the previous selections. This is working well. However, I would like the displayed results to include a clickable link as well as the other info. Right now I'm using document.write to open a new window with the link on it. This is not ideal.

```
    function formatHyper(hyper) {
    var NewWindow = window.open('', 'name', 'height=660,width=650,status=1');
    var str = "Parts";

    NewWindow.document.write(str.link(hyper));

}
```

Hyper is the text link. Being called from an external .cs file that looks like this:

```
public class PhonePrice
{
private static List<Phone> Phones = new List<Phone>{
    new Phone{Make="Apple",Model="iPhone    4",Carrier="ATT",Colour="black",Price=00.00f,Hyper="http://www.google.com"},
```

When I complete the last dropdown selection it will display info about my selection but it then opens a new window with just the link. If I remove the NewWindow variable, it will load just the link in the current page, thus making it to where I can't see any of the other returned data.

I would like it to work like the currency does. But instead of adding a $ I want it to convert the text into a URL

```
    function formatPrice(price) {
    return "$" + price.toFixed(2);
}
```

Here is what it looks like when it opens the clickable link in a new window. I would like the clickable link to appear where it says undefined.

**Apple iPhone 4

Carrier ATT

Colour: black

Hyper: undefined

Price: $00.00**

Please help!!

[Here's a link to the full code](http://www.2shared.com/file/fFgPZGQm/CDD.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO, why are you calling `link(hyper)` on a string object?  What does your `link` function look like?

Comment: @philipvr Thanks! Like I said, I'm a total novice. Most of this code is copied from examples I've found on the web. I don't think I even have a link function... 'Hyper' is being called from an external .cs list. It looks like this.

    public class PhonePrice
{
    private static List<Phone> Phones = new List<Phone>{
        new Phone{Make="Apple",Model="iPhone 4",Carrier="ATT",Colour="black",Price=00.00f,Hyper="http://www.google.com"},

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Line 23 of the CascadingDropDowns.cshtml file.  Change:

```
<p>Hyper: ${formatHyper(Hyper)}</p>
```

to:

```
<p>Hyper: <a id="link">${formathyper(hyper)}</a></p>
```

If there is only one link then this will work.  If there could be more than one, then you will need to make each ID match the hyper value (assuming it is unique).

I couldn't test this with your code, but it should work.  And the function from the first answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var texttheysee = 'My Link'; 
$(function formathyper(hyper) { 
    $('a#link').attr('href', hyper); 
    $('a#link').text(texttheysee); 
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The var hyper is populated in an external .cs file. The main code is in a CSHTML document. How would I implement this? I just edited my original question and added a link to the files. Anyway you could take a look?

Comment: hmm..yes my answer isn't the best answer for your scenario.  Let me look at the code and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I thought it was going to work! For some reason it's not. Even after messing around with it for a while. All that happens is now instead of displaying 'undefined' it doesn't display anything... What do you think?